# Organize a group of enums

Tags: typescript, enums

Im writing code with typescript and i have file that include 6 different enum.
I want from another file to import all the enums together so i try the following syntax:

```
import * from './ModelsEnums' as Enums
```

when 'ModelsEnums.ts' is the file that has all the enums as follow:

```
    export enum ENUM1{
          .enter code here
          .
          .
    }

    export enum ENUM2{
          .
          .
          .
    }
.
.
.
    export enum ENUM6{
          .
          .
          .
    }
```

but this one won't work for me, how should i do it?
btw i want to avoid from the following syntax:

```
import {enum1, enum2, ..., enum6} from './ModelsEnums'
```

Comment: Just got the `as Enums` in the wrong place. It's `import * as Enums from './ModelsEnums'`

Comment: `import * as enums from './ModelsEnums'` then `enums.ENUM1`, `enums.ENUM2`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you have different enum:

```
export enum Cat {
    Ragdoll,
    Birman,
    Abyssinian
}

export enum Dog {
    Bulldog,
    Boxer,
    Doberman
}
```

You can group them in a `type`:

```
export type Animal = Cat | Dog;
```